# Saving dates in SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I've found this from this link:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class
> set aside for storing dates and/or
> times. Instead, the built-in Date And
> Time Functions of SQLite are capable
> of storing dates and times as TEXT,
> REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD
> HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> **REAL** as Julian day
> numbers, the number of days since noon
> in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.
> according to the proleptic Gregorian
> calendar.
>
> **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the
> number of seconds since 1970-01-01
> 00:00:00 UTC. Applications can chose
> to store dates and times in any of
> these formats and freely convert
> between formats using the built-in
> date and time functions.date and time functions.

I'm a bit confused as to which I should use. I'm creating a Windows Forms C# application and will be using the built `DateTime` control.

Which option would best suit me? I think `TEXT` would, but maybe I'm mistaken. I'm new to SQLite.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)? Even if SQLite itself doesn't recognize datetime data type, this data provider recognizes it.

For example, if you use SQLiteDataAdapter to populate a datatable with a select statement, if the data type of a column is datetime, the returned datacolumn will be datetime.

There is limitation to the provider: it can't guess data type when your select contains more than one table. In this case, you can declare the returning data type yourself by prepending your query like this:

```
types [integer], [text], [boolean], [datetime];
select A.id, A.subject, B.isactive, B.due_date from ...
```

The provider stores the data as text like `2009-04-01 17:42:38.828125`. SQLite is fine with this format, for example you can calculate the next day with:

```
select datetime('2009-04-01 17:42:38.828125', '+1 days');
```

EDIT: you specify data type as datetime like this:

```
create table C ( d datetime );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Text and haven't had any problem with it.